# Catching DoEvents in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, doevents

I'm writing excel/vba to read a word file and parse through the contents, creating a CSV file from those contents.

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
with doc
    for each para in doc.paragraphs
        DoEvents
        txt = trim(para.range.text)
        debug.print txt
    next 
end with
```

More code will be forthcoming as I figure this out. However, I have encountered a problem when I click the stop button in the developer ribbon - the doevents does catch it and stop running. However, the windows file is still open and it causes an error for the next time around.
Is there a way to catch the doevents and have it close all the other open files?

Comment: You would "catch DoEvents" as soon as you moved the mouse one pixel. So thankfully, no.

Comment: Maybe look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enablecancelkey  (for use with Esc)

Comment: Ah, yes, that looks like the right way to do it. I was heading down the wrong path. tx